# jQuery - $.extend deep loses reference to array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have observed an odd issue in jQuery's `$.extend` method and referencing an array (which is considered an Object in JavaScript).

I use a defaults object, defined as follows:

```
var defaults = {
    numbers: []
};
```

I have a config option I then pass a function, defined as follows:

```
var config = {
    numbers: [1, 2, 3]
};
```

Within a function, I extend these two (using a deep `$.extend`):

```
function configure(settings) {
    var nums = $.extend(true, {}, defaults, settings);

    nums.numbers.push(4);

    console.log(settings, nums);
}

configure(config);
```

When I log these two, the results are as follows:

```
settings: {"numbers":[1,2,3]}
nums: {"numbers":[1,2,3,4]}
```

What I am failing to understand is, jQuery merges the objects from left to right.

I would expect that since settings is the last object that is extended, the numbers array that's created in `nums` is a reference to `settings.numbers` (since `settings` is the last object to be `$.extend`ed). This is not the case (as you can see when I log the final results).

Can somebody please explain why? It was the cause of a difficult to find bug in my app so want to ensure I understand it so it does not happen again.

Comment: This is exactly what a deep copy means -- it will copy all the contents of the `numbers` array into a new array. Do a shallow copy if you want to only copy the reference to the array object. Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/184710/what-is-the-difference-between-a-deep-copy-and-a-shallow-copy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a deep merge:

> On a deep extend, Object and Array are extended

The target object is the first object after your `deep` boolean.

In your case, it's `{}` and also `nums` because of your assignation.

`settings` isn't the target object. Its `numbers` array is therefore not the one of `nums`.

Comment: Understood and thanks! Is there a trick to reassign the `nums.numbers` reference back to `settings.numbers`?

Comment: @keldar In your case it looks like you could simply do a non deep merge: `var nums = $.extend({}, defaults, settings);`

Comment: Unfortunately my full config is a little more complex than the code shown here so a non-deep merge isn't an option in this instance.

Comment: The just set the reference manually, if you need a special behavior